# Adding a duplicate item on to a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add the last item of a list onto the list my code is:

```
def dup_last(data):
    data.append([-1])
    return data
```

and calling for the function is:

```
item = dup_last([1,2,3])
print(item)
```

but I want my output to be within only one set of brackets like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: It's good to also include the output you're getting, so we can see why it's wrong :).

Comment: @tomknight FYI your function crashes if `data` is empty.

Comment: @tomknight, did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept it :).

Answer (score 3):

```
data.append([-1])
```

Here you are appending `[-1]`, a list with an element of `-1`, change it to:

```
data.append(data[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks Yu Hao. I didn't realize you had to do that, one more lesson learnt.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, I would also suggest to use slicing notation `[:]` when dealing with lists to prevent getting `list index out of range` errors in case there is no item:

```
def dup_last(data):
    data.append(data[-1])
    return data
```

The above function will raise `IndexError` if `data` is empty list:

```
>>> print dup_last([])
----> 2     data.append(data[-1])
      3     return data
      4
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When you update your function as follows, you no longer get that kind of error:

```
def dup_last(data):
    data.extend(data[-1:])
    return data
```

---

```
>>> print dup_last([])
[]
>>> print dup_last([1])
[1, 1]
>>> print dup_last([1, 2])
[1, 2, 2]
```

There is a good explanation in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) about how slicing works in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `data.append(data[-1])`; `data.append([-1])` appends a value which is a list containing only `-1`, so your result will be `[1, 2, 3, [-1]]`.

Note that this will modify the list in-place, so whichever list you pass in will also have the last element duplicated, not just the list you get out (though they could be the same list).

I wouldn't use a function for this; just do `data.append(data[-1])` instead of `data = dup_last(data)`, or even `dup_last(data)`. Also, it's probably better to just add the duplicate manually if you're working with a list literal; `data = [1, 2, 3, 3]` vs `data = dup_last([1, 2, 3])` or similar.